# Can I tell one div to use an image from another div. CSS JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a HTML file containing a parent div.  In my JS code 16 child divs are created within the parent.  What I want to do is input an image and have the parent div fit the image so that it fills the container.  Then have each child div take the respective image from the parent div.

I am trying to make a slider puzzle game but unlike other posts on here I want the user to be able to input their own image regardless of size.  I currently am using background position to assign each child element a portion of the picture, however this only works for images larger than the container.

The essence of what I am trying to do is tell div1 to use the background image from div2 as its own.

Here is a link to my jsfiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/tdammon/zsthogrm/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    let sq = 4

    let size = $("#image").width()
    let boxSize = size / sq
    let $url
    $('#gameImage').keypress(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 13){
            $url = $('#gameImage').val();
            console.log($url);
            for(let i=0;i<16;i++){
                let x = ((i%4) * boxSize)
                let y = (Math.floor(i/4) * boxSize)
                //$('#image').css("backgroundImage", `url(${$url})`);
                $('#image').append('<div class="piece" id= 
                "segment'+i+'"></div>')
                document.getElementById("segment"+i).style.width = 
                `${boxSize}`;
                document.getElementById("segment"+i).style.height = 
                `${boxSize}`;
                $('#segment'+i).css("backgroundImage", `url(${$url})`);                
        document.getElementById("segment"+i).style.backgroundPosition = 
        `-${x}px -${y}px`;
            }
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: For the image size you could check and if its less than what you expect use background-size xxx% so you will cover.
But you would have the problem with the aspect ratio of the image. 
So the divs should be created dinamically based on the proporcion/aspect ratio of the image and if the size of the image is less you could use the background-size or make some validation to upload a bigger image.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answer your stated question, although I think swapping out a background image should be fairly simple.
But if the underlying problem is simply switching the order of two divs, I would think having your divs in a CSS grid and swapping the row or column might be easier?

Answer (score 0):

Still not a direct answer, but it would be way simpler with just a `background-size` on your pieces.

To take your example (I just added one line in the css) :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    let sq = 4

    let size = $("#image").width()
    let boxSize = size / sq
    let $url
    $('#gameImage').keypress(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 13){
            $url = $('#gameImage').val();
            console.log($url);
            for(let i=0;i<16;i++){
                let x = ((i%4) * boxSize)
                let y = (Math.floor(i/4) * boxSize)
                //$('#image').css("backgroundImage", `url(${$url})`);
                $('#image').append('<div class="piece" id= "segment'+i+'"></div>')
                document.getElementById("segment"+i).style.width = `${boxSize}`;
                document.getElementById("segment"+i).style.height = `${boxSize}`;
                $('#segment'+i).css("backgroundImage", `url(${$url})`);
                document.getElementById("segment"+i).style.backgroundPosition = `-${x}px -${y}px`;
            }
        }
    });
    

})
```

```css
#gameImage {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}

h3 {
    text-align: center;
}

#image {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    border: solid black;
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    background-size: cover;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.piece {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: -1px -1px -1px -1px;
    height: 25%;
    width: 25%;
    background-size: 600px 600px; /*just one line here*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Puzzle Game</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--[if lt IE 7]>
            <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="#">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->
        <div>
            <h3> Enter Image Here</h3>
            <input placeholder="image" id="gameImage">
        </div>
        <div id="image">

        </div>
        <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="main.js" async defer></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Of course you can push it further with automatic calculation of the size of the grid and the `background-size` of the pieces. As long as both are equals, it should work.